# How to set Add two functions to 'onchange's in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i am new to Reactjs, Still struggling to learn react. I have some problem related how i can call two functions in one `onChange` Event, I tried alot but did't get idea how it would be possible. Could You please help me. Thank You

**Function 1**

```
handleChange = ({ fileList }) => this.setState({ fileList });
```

**Function 2**

```
handleUpload = e => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const storeUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    reader.onload = function(upload) {
      fetch(`http://..../api/s3/uploadtoaws`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: storeUser._id,
          type: 'employee',
          content: upload.target.result,
          key: e.file.name,
          oldKey: '',
        }),
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => {
          console.warn(res);
        });
      // .done();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.file.originFileObj);
  };
```

**Event Implementation**

```
    <Upload
            listType="picture-card"
            fileList={fileList}
            onPreview={this.handlePreview}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
```

Comment: Why not have the one event handler call the other two functions?

Comment: Tried but not working

Comment: You might want to show what you tried.

Comment: Actually currently I am working on Photo Upload . I used two function one is about HandleUpload and 2nd one is HandleChange. I want to call it through onchange event but it not working

Answer (score 2):

Just call the function inside JSX with specified argument, however it's important to use  your `handleUpload` function as a currying function, so you will have access to both `event` and `fileList`.

`onChange={this.handleUpload(someObj)}`

```
handleUpload = ({ fileList }) => (e) => { // fileList is a field in someObj
    this.setState({ fileList });

    const reader = new FileReader();
    const storeUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    reader.onload = function(upload) {
      fetch(`http://..../api/s3/uploadtoaws`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: storeUser._id,
          type: 'employee',
          content: upload.target.result,
          key: e.file.name,
          oldKey: '',
        }),
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => {
          console.warn(res);
        });
      // .done();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.file.originFileObj);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't getting you

Comment: @Brad Edited it

Comment: What i may write in (SomeObj) ?

Comment: @Brad The object that contains that `fileList`

Comment: Tried but not working Could you please help me to review my code where i may mistake 

`  onChange={this.handleUpload({ fileList })}`

Comment: tried, but not working. Could you please help me to review my code
`onChange={this.handleUpload({ fileList })}`

Comment: @Brad It's correct. It should work now. `console.log(fileList)` in your `handleUpload` and show me the result

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'originFileObj' of undefined`

Comment: @Brad `e.file` is not defined. You should probably change your `onChange` function into `onDrop` ---> `onDrop={this.handleUpload({ fileList })}`

Comment: @Brad Brad, Ive edited my answer. Just switched `e` with `fileList` in the arguments. Now it should work properly